# Search based on count of particular word

Tags: xml, xquery

Below is a sample XML file.

```
<Docs>
 <Doc>
  <Name>Doc 1</Name>
  <Info>Hurray</Info>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Name>Doc 2</Name>
  <Info>Brinjal is king of vegetables.</Info>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Name>Doc 3</Name>
  <Info>Alexandar was a great king. His desire was to conquer the world and rule the  world as a king.</Info>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Name>Doc 4</Name>
  <Info>I love cherries.</Info>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Name>Doc 5</Name>
  <Info>Mango is king of fruits. Alphonso is king of mangoes. So Alphonso is king's king.</Info>
 </Doc>
</Docs>
```

I want to search the  tag for the word "king" and return the  as output. I know this is simple... :)

But the order of the  should be in order of the word searched (here it will be king) ie the most numbers will come first.

Doc 5 (3 times king)
Doc 3 (2 times king)
Doc 2 (1 time king)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked the question before on the BaseX mailing list I assume that you are using BaseX as processor. Assuming that `$doc` holds the provided xml input, the following shows the desired result:

```
for $e in $doc//Doc
let $copy := copy $c := $e/Info modify () return $c
let $count := ft:count($copy[. contains text 'King'])
order by $count descending
where $count > 0
return <Result>{$e/Name}<count>{$count}</count></Result>
```

There are two things special here:

- The `$copy` statement is a simple copy and necessary, because `ft:count` is expecting a *database node* as input. If your fragment is already in the database you don't need this.
- `ft:count` is vendor-specific to BaseX, unfortunately it is not part of the Full Text specification.

Comment: drikk-  But, I think the `where` clause should come before the `order by`

Comment: You are right. Interestingly, it also does work in BaseX with `order by` before `where`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by`.

```
let $token := 'king'
for $doc in //Doc
let $count := count(tokenize($doc/Info, "[\W]")[lower-case(.) = lower-case($token)])
where $count > 0
order by $count descending
return concat($doc/Name, " (", $count, " time", "s"[$count>1], " ", $token, ")")
```

*This expression splits on non-word characters `\W`. Depending on your application, you might want to use another regular expression for tokenization.*

Answer (score 0):

One more example to get desired output is:

```
for $Doc in doc("file:/C:/Users/vgv/Desktop/Testing/Untitled1.xml")//Doc
let $DocName := $Doc/Name/text()
let $KingCount := count(tokenize($Doc/Info,'king'))
order by $KingCount descending
return
concat($DocName, ' (', $KingCount, ' times king)')
```

Comment: Counts to many "king"s (one too much for every document). Also, for example counts "kingsized" which definitely does not equal the word "king".